How to call a C# DLL with custom type input from Powershell
Let us say I have a C# DLL which contains a class AdditionLibrary as below
namespace AdditionLibrary
{
    public static class AdditionOperation
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public struct AddNumbers
        {
            public int a;
            public int b;
        }
        public static int AddNum(AddNumbers addNum)
        {
            return addNum.a + addNum.b;
        }
    }
}

I want to call Add & AddNum methods of this class from powershell.
I can easily call Add method since it is POD data type (int) like below from powershell.
Add-Type -Path "AdditionLibrary.dll"
$result = [AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation]::Add(100,200)

How to call AddNum method which requires custom type AddNumbers?
Can it be possible without embedding code inside powershell like below & call through invoke-expression ?
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 

I do not know how to create instance of AddNumbers in powershell and pass that as a parameter to C# DLL.

its unclear what you mean by "Can it be possible without embedding code inside powershell like below & call through invoke-expression ?" you're already doing that just below that sentence

@SantiagoSquarzon no I am not embedding any code from powershell . I am loading C# DLL (Add-Type) and then calling the exported method.

Embedding code means something like this from powershell
$code = @"
using System;
namespace AdditionLib
{
public static class Addition$id1
{
public static void Add2Numbers(int i,int j){
Console.WriteLine("Addition of 2 numbers {0} & {1} is {2}",i,j,i+j);
}
}
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

Yeah, that works fine. Your code compiles using typedefinition even in powershell 5.1 (c# 5 compiler)

You just need the correct type literal syntax for nested types: $result = [AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation]::Add([AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation+AddNumbers]@{ a = 1; b = 2 })

@SantiagoSquarzon, there are 2 codes which are in separate file. One is C# code which is a part of a DLL. Another is a powershell code which calls it.

So instead of hardcoded you can read the file content into Add-Type like Add-Type (Get-Content otherfile.cs -Raw) it should still work

For the first question:

Can it be possible without embedding code inside powershell like below & call through Invoke-Expression ?

I understand from comments that you have your cs file with this code, in that case instead of hardcoding it in PowerShell you can read the content and pass it to Add-Type. There is no need for Invoke-Expression.
Add-Type (Get-Content somefile.cs -Raw)

As for the second question:

How to call AddNum method which requires custom type AddNumbers ?

You can reference nested types in your class using the + sign, like: [Namespace.Type+NestedType], so in your case to reference AddNumbers you would use [AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation+AddNumbers].
Then for instantiating, you can use the hashtable syntax to create an instance of AddNumbers. Since your struct has an empty ctor and the fields aren't marked as readonly this syntax should work for them. See Creating Objects from hashtables for more info.
Add-Type '
namespace AdditionLibrary
{
    public static class AdditionOperation
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public struct AddNumbers
        {
            public int a;
            public int b;
        }
        public static int AddNum(AddNumbers addNum)
        {
            return addNum.a + addNum.b;
        }
    }
}'

$addNum = [AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation+AddNumbers]@{
    a = 1
    b = 2
}

[AdditionLibrary.AdditionOperation]::AddNum($addNum) # 3


Thanks a lot @SantiagoSquarzon. This is working for me.

@GajananaDS, if this is working for you, please select the check mark so that other people will know this is the best answer. This is how SO works.

Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon. I marked the answer as accepted.
